Extend a character on closed algebra to the whole algebra possible?
Let $B\subsetneq A$ be C*-algebras. We know every state $f$ on $B$ can be extended to a state $\tilde{f}$ on $A$. Is it still true if replacing "state" with "character"?

If $h: B\to \mathbb{C}$ is a homomorphism. Does there always exist a homomorphism $\tilde{h}:A\to \mathbb{C}$ s.t. $\tilde{h}|_B=h$?

We also know, every character on a C*-algebra is a *-homomorphism and is a positive  functional. It seems we need a maximal ideal $M\subset A$ s.t. $M\cap B=\text{Ker}(h)$. Is this the right way to think about it? Thanks in advance.

No, this is quite false and you can find finite-dimensional counterexamples, e.g. take $B$ to be commutative and $A = M_n(\mathbb{C}), n \ge 2$. I think it's true if $B, A$ are both unital and commutative by the commutative Gelfand-Naimark theorem.

As Qiaochu mentioned, this is definitely false as stated. In general, in the noncommutative case you should not think about characters, but rather pure states. Indeed, any pure state on $B$ can be extended to a pure state on $A$. For commutative $C^\ast$-algebras, pure states are exactly characters, so that gives you what you want if you assume $A$ is commutative.

@DavidGao So if both $A,B$ are unital and $B$ commutative, a character $h$ on $B$ is a pure state, and can be extended to a pure state $f$ on $A$, and that's the best we can get in general cases?

@user760 You don’t need unitality, nor do you need to assume $B$ is commutative. (Any character on a $C^\ast$-algebra will be a pure state, regardless of whether that $C^\ast$-algebra is commutative or not. It’s the converse, namely any pure state is a character, that requires commutativity.) So you get any character on $B$ can be extended to a pure state on $A$, without any additional assumptions. But that’s basically the best you can get in the general case.
